# Is a Freudian slip a reason to close question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I've found this question: [How to avoid polar bear in Antarctica?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7821/how-to-avoid-attack-from-polar-bear) closed because it was too localized. Yest, there are no polar bears in Antarctica, but they live in Arctica, which was what the OP had probably in mind.

After edit this would be a good question, IMHO.

Wasn't the closing this question a bit too hasty?

Comment: he did reply to the mods and state that he really does want to avoid polar bears in Antarctica.  :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Or the user could be trolling. Our intention here is not to divine out what the OP means or doesn't mean. Questions once closed can always be reopened once they are edited (and this is done on Travel.SE too).

Comment: agreed.  The 'localised' option was just chosen as we don't have a 'potential trolling' option, but anyone's always welcome to edit their question and flag for consideration to reopen.

Comment: Yep if the OP comes along and edits it to "The Arctic circle" etc I would *consider* re-opening but so far it looks like trolling to me too.